# ErrorAccessDenied when requesting Microsoft Graph calendar resources via client credentials OAuth flow

Tags: azure, graph, oauth-2.0, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I needed to access resource room's events via the Microsoft Graph API in a server-to-server environment so I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) guide a few months ago. I created the application, set the calendar-related Application Permissions required and used an admin account to consent to the permissions successfully. Everything has been working for a good 3-4 months now without issues.

However, after not changing anything, today I am getting this response back from the `/v1.0/users/{resource room email}/events` endpoint:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "952955b5-562e-4fa6-8b0f-e381c8294fcd",
      "date": "2017-09-06T03:09:49"
    }
  }
}
```

This appears to be a permissions issue as the `/v1.0/users/{resource room email}/messages` endpoint returns the resource room's messages just fine (assuming permissions are set).

If I follow the previously linked guide using CURL I can replicate the issue.

Get a token:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d 'client_id=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=XXXXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials' \
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tennant URL}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Try and get the events:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{resource room email}/events'
```

And I receive the same error as above.

Has something changed that I am unaware of that would break this functionality?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm, in the docs it looks like it should be `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events`? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_events. You should also check that the JWT contains the role *Calendars.Read*.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, though the "resource room email" I listed is the "id" that is specified in the docs.

Anyway, it looks like this was a Microsoft Bug as running the exact same code around 4 hours later saw everything working fine.

Comment: :D Good that it was solved.